# How to reset a Material Angular select's value to its label from TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'd like to get rid of the value of this select, and set it back to `<mat-label>Select Member</mat-label>` in the TypeScript when an internal event occurs. I haven't found a way to do this on the TypeScript side. Any suggestions?

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
<mat-label>Select Member</mat-label>
<mat-select (selectionChange)="getAthleteAnalytics($event.value)" id="member-select">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let member of members" [value]="member.id">
        {{member.firstName}} {{member.lastName}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Use reactive forms. "Reactive forms provide synchronous access to the data model, immutability with observable operators, and change tracking through observable streams."  https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all it is better to use ReactiveForms in your case, but anyway you can still work like this

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Select Member</mat-label>
  <mat-select
    #model="matSelect"
    (selectionChange)="getAthleteAnalytics(model)"
    id="member-select"
  >
    <mat-option *ngFor="let member of members" [value]="member.id">
      {{ member.firstName }} {{ member.lastName }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

and here is the code of component ts file

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  latestSelectedValue :number |undefined;

  members = [
    {id: 1 , firstName:"Ahmed" , lastName:"Mostafa"},
    {id: 2 , firstName:"Mohamed" , lastName:"Mostafa"},
    {id: 3 , firstName:"Ebrahem" , lastName:"Mostafa"},
    {id: 4 , firstName:"Hba" , lastName:"Mostafa"},
  ]

  getAthleteAnalytics(model: MatSelect): void {
    // here you got the selected value   
    this.latestSelectedValue = model.value;
    // if you want to reset the select after that just make the value null or undefined 
    // im calling an mehtod to do that for me 
    // i wrap it inside timeout to show you the selcted value first on the control then after 3 seconds will reset it to null
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.resetSelection(model)
    },3000)
    
  }

  resetSelection(select: MatSelect){
    select.value = null;
  }
}
```

also if you want the full example here is stackblitz
[click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-unaens?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for this. This solves my issue. However, what if I decide I want to set the select.value to the first element when I listen to a change from a subscription. Can I still do similar logic even though I don't have access to the "model: MatSelect" in the typescript? Is there a way to get access to it?

Comment: yes you can read it from the @ViewChild decorator

her is the example from the component ts file 
```
@ViewChild('model',{static: true}) model: MatSelect

```
also check the link again i updated it for you